# Cookies security

Tags: php, security, session, cookies

I'm implementing my first user login and I've read some posts here on Stack about the convenience of store login infos in **sessions** or **cookies**, but my main question is still there: is it so unsafe storing the userID/userCode in a cookie to let the user stay logged in?

In other words, is it possible to download the cookie on a pen drive, downloading it into another PC, connect to the website and be recognized as logged in? If so, how giants like Facebook and Amazon had implemented this system avoiding security issues?

Should completely avoid, then, the use of cookies for this purpose in favor of sessions (although the user has to *log in every time*)?

Since I have to collect sensitive informations I would like to build the safest system I can.

Comment: Because of session hijacking and the possibility of modifying cookies, you should always be cautious. Never store any data in plain text, if you want it to be kept secure.

Comment: As @Hallur mentioned there is always some vulnerability. You can minimise this by cross checking your sessions, ensuring you incapacitate XSS attack and so on. Bare in mind to many of these checks can add considerable overhead to you pageloads

Comment: @Hallur Sure I could make a cookie "unreadable" hashing it, but in this case of user login, wouldn't be useless if the aim is to store the userdID/code that will be checked by a PHP script? In other words, if I have access to the cookie and I "steal" it, it's the same if it's readable or not 'cause the way the PHP script read it is always the same, no?

Comment: @scottevans93 Thanks Scott, you gave me a couple of precious keywords on  which I'm gonna search more infos

Comment: How come people always try to store data in a cookie. Have you never read any privacy statement or legal cookie notice? You should.

Comment: _“if I have access to the cookie and I "steal" it, it's the same if it's readable or not 'cause the way the PHP script read it is always the same, no?”_ - yes, but that is not the issue. If you only stored an unencrypted user id, then I would not have to steal your cookie - all I would need to know is your user id, and then I can send my own cookie containing that id.

Comment: @CBroe but Facebook stores the userID in a cookie without even hashing it or something else; that's why I was wondering which other system it would be possible to implement (of course Facebook will surely have tons of layered security checks and I'm not Facebook, but understanding the method could be useful)

Comment: @DanFromGermany Surely cookies can be manipulated and read but there's no legal statement which avoids to store data into a cookie. The European privacy regulation impose you to store **sensitive informations** in the safest way possible, but I can store any other data in a cookie. So maybe I didn't get the aim of your answer

Comment: _“but Facebook stores the userID in a cookie without even hashing it or something else”_ - yes, but they sure as heck won’t be using (only) that to identify a logged-in user.

Comment: @CBroe Which (safe) method would you suggest, than, to maintain a user logged in?

Comment: This is too broad a topic to fully discuss here; so I would suggest some more reading-up on the whole issue. Rule-of-thumb: You are likely not in a position to implement a proper login system, while you still have to ask questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

Safely variant:
Store in Cookie a SESSION ID (32-64 symbols, random string).

By SESSION_ID (Stored in Cookie) open the session storage (Stored on server and not avaliable for user access) and work with that (You may write into session storage user id|token or another actions).

In PHP - See $_SESSION and $_COOKIE

And one more moment in PHP (7+): php.ini parameter - session.sid_length (Set session id string length)

Comment: Nice tip, I'm gonna try it; although I didn't understand the `random string` part

Comment: random string - string with fixed length and random symbols.

Comment: ... random string generate for new session - this string will ass session id.